# ¿Cuál es el plural de "táper"?

Tags: sustantivos, plurales, extranjerismos

Ahora que la RAE ha admitido (¡por fin!) la palabra *[táper](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z7mZk4e)* en el diccionario, me entra la duda: ¿cuál es su forma plural? [Según el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i) sería "táperes", igual que "másteres" o "pósteres", pero me suena horrible (supongo que por la falta de uso). ¿Es esa la forma con la que la gente suele formar hoy día el plural? ¿O se usa más la forma "tapers"? ¿O incluso dejarlo invariable?

Comment: Yo digo *tapers* pero también digo *posters* así que mi criterio no cuenta.

Comment: Se nota que la respuesta correcta seria terminando en `res`, pero en realidad yo diría `tapers`, `masters` y `posters`... creo que aprender ingles afecto un poco mi vocabulario...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues tenemos la respuesta de la RAE a un tuit que pregunta como escribir *tupper* y le contestan esto:

> .#RAEconsultas Precisamente «táper», pl. «táperes», es la grafía que
>   recomendamos en español como adaptación gráfica del inglés «tupper
>   (ware)».

Enlace al tuit original y captura de la respuesta que da la RAE:

https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/933346538008477697
[image]

Así que según la RAE el plural es *táperes* sin lugar a dudas.